# Is there a way to access the properties of several identical components on a page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I’m just starting to master Vue and decided to make a small application for calculating the sum of fractions.
I have two components: Fraction.vue and App.vue. App.vue contains several Fraction components.

Fraction.vue code:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      numerator: 0,
      denominator: 1
    };
  },
  computed: {
    result() {
      return (this.numerator / this.denominator).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
};
```

App.vue code:

```
 <template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="fractions">
      <Fraction v-for="fraction in fractions" :key="fraction">
        <span v-if="fractions.indexOf(fraction) === fractions.length - 1">
          =
        </span>
        <span v-else>+</span>
      </Fraction>
      <div class="result">
        <span>{{ result }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="add-fraction">
      <button @click="addFraction">Add fraction</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Fraction from "./Fraction";
export default {
  components: {
    Fraction: Fraction
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fractions: [1, 2]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addFraction() {
      if (this.fractions.length !== 5) {
        this.fractions.push(this.getRandomInt(1, 100));
      } else {
        alert("The maximum number of fractions in the expression is 5.");
      }
    },
    getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result() {
      return 213;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I dont know how to get final result of equation.

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve here. But you should just have `<Fraction v-for="fraction in fractions" :key="fraction"></Fracton>` in your template and the inner span has to be in the template of `Fraction`. Otherwise you have to use `slot`.

Comment: Are you trying to get the computed `result` of `Fraction` to display in `App`? I would think the best way is to create `result` in `App`s data hook, and pass it through to `Fraction` with `v-bind`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is of aproach, you haven't quite understanded how does vue works. In the spirit of learning more code and less explaining. I simplified your example so you get my point.

Fraction.vue

```
//You can render information in your components
//Every component you make can have its own template
<template>
  <div>
    {{ result }}
  </div>

</template>
export default {
  props: {
    numerator: Number,
    denominator: Number
  },
  computed: {
    result() {
      return (this.numerator / this.denominator).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
};
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="fractions">
      //<!-- See here this is the easiest way to pass values to a component -->
      <Fraction 
        v-for="(fraction, index) in fractions" 
        :key="index" 
        :numerator="fraction.numerator"
        :denominator="fraction.denominator"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Fraction from "./Fraction";
export default {
  components: {
    Fraction: Fraction
  },
  data() {
    return {
      //Arrays can have nested objects, and this objects can be anonymous
      fractions: [
        {
          numerator: 1,
          denominator: 2
        },
        {
          numerator: 2,
          denominator: 1
        },  
      ]
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

If what you wanted is to have a reusable piece of code components are the wrong way of doing it, in that case you should use a mixin.